# How to use Go's type alias to make own models work with protobufs?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, rpc, twirp

I've got some REST API with my models defined as Go structs.

```
type User struct {
  FirstName string
  LastName  string
}
```

Then I've got my database methods for getting data.

```
GetUserByID(id int) (*User, error)
```

Now I'd like to replace my REST API with https://github.com/twitchtv/twirp .

Therefore I started defining my models inside `.proto` files.

```
message User {
  string first_name = 2;
  string last_name = 3;
}
```

Now I've got two `User` types. Let's call them the **native** and the **proto** type.

I've also got a service defined in my `.proto` file which returns a user to the frontend.

```
service Users {
  rpc GetUser(Id) returns (User);
}
```

This generates an interface that I have to fill in.

```
func (s *Server) GetUser(context.Context, id) (*User, error) {
  // i'd like to reuse my existing database methods
  u, err := db.GetUserByID(id)
  // handle error
  // do more stuff
  return u, nil
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. My database returns a **native** User but the interface requires a **proto** user.

Is there an easy way to make it work? Maybe using `type aliases`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you don't want your database package to depend on the protobuf types, you have to do the conversion manually. If the types are sufficiently similar, you may get away with json.Marshal and json.Unmarshal, for instance. You should include the generated types in the question, so we get an idea how they differ.

Comment: And type aliases are definitely not a solution. Aliases don't create new types, only new names for existing types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can solve your problem is by doing the conversion **manually**.

```
type User struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName string
}

type protoUser struct {
    firstName string
    lastName string
}

func main() {
    u := db() // Retrieve a user from a mocked db

    fmt.Println("Before:")
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", *u) // What db returns (*protoUser)
    fmt.Println("After:")
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", u.AsUser()) // What conversion returns (User)
}

// Mocked db that returns pointer to protoUser
func db() *protoUser {
    pu := protoUser{"John", "Dough"}
    return &pu
}

// Conversion method (converts protoUser into a User)
func (pu *protoUser) AsUser() User {
    return User{pu.firstName, pu.lastName}
}
```

> The key part is the `AsUser` method on the `protoUser` struct.
>   There we simply write our custom logic for converting a `protoUser` into a `User` type we want to be working with.

### [Working Example](https://play.golang.org/p/TsstNNhvy-h)

Answer (score 0):

As [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603316/peter) mentioned in the comment section.

I've seen a project which made it with a custom `Convert` function. It converts the Protobuf to local struct via `json.Unmarshal`, not sure how's the performance but it's a way to go.

**Preview Code** [<kbd>PLAYGROUND</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/uVSGoDRjSQW)

```golang
// Convert converts the in struct to out struct via `json.Unmarshal`
func Convert(in interface{}, out interface{}) error {
    j, err := json.Marshal(in)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(j, &out)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    // Converts the protobuf struct to local struct via json.Unmarshal
    var localUser User
    if err := convert(protoUser, &localUser); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

**Output**

```sh
Before:
main.ProtoUser{FirstName:"John", LastName:"Dough"}
After:
main.User{FirstName:"John", LastName:"Dough"}

Program exited.
```